# R: How to create a specific loop and ifelse statements for my data set. (DATA SET ATTACHED)

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am new to R and I would like to seek your advice on the type of code that could assist me in performing a complex task. I have a set of variables that contain pass or fail values. Base on these values, the test function should accomplish the tasks written below:

1. Check if Normal == Fail, if true create a new column called test which inserts "Fail" into the column for that particular case.
2. If normal == Fail, is false, check from PD to SA == Fail. If true, inserting "Fail" into the column named test that was created in step 1.
3. If PD to SA == Fail is false, insert "pass" into the column named test that was created in step 1.
4. Any NAs in a particular case should be skipped.

Ideally, the table at the end should look like this:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpqSA.png)

As you can see from example 1, Even though normal == pass, because TH == Fail, the end result of the test column was "fail".

In [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y32dZ.png), All values from normal to SA == pass, the end result of the test column == "Pass".

Lastly in [Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVZaa.png), because normal == "Fail", the end result of the test column == "Fail".

I have been trying to create this function and iterate it through the 2000 cases in my dataset. But none has worked. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have attached the link to my dataset in the question for reference.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nd0c99kuMiUdjhiKxNHK-j5TY9de9vbX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I understood your problem correctly,

in this specific case, something like this should work

A_

```
require(readr)
require(dplyr)

data <- read_delim('~/Downloads/datahelp.csv', delim = ',')

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(test = 'Pass',
         test = ifelse(Normal == 'Fail', 'Fail', test),
         test = ifelse(Normal != 'Fail' & (PD=='Fail'| MP=='Fail'| TH=='Fail'| Py=='Fail'| KA=='Fail'| VT=='Fail'| SA=='Fail'), 'Fail', test))
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, Thank you so much for your help. It worked! Could you please explain the logic behind the code?

Comment: it simply says


`set test = Pass`

`if Normal = Fail then Fail else test`

`if Normal != Fail & (any of PD:SA) = Fail then Fail else Test`
```

Comment: Oh I understand it now. Thank you so much~

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr and `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(Test=case_when(
    Normal=="Fail" ~ "Fail", 
    Normal!="Fail" & rowSums(select(., PD:SA) == "Fail", na.rm=TRUE) > 0 ~ "Fail",
    Normal=="Pass" ~ "Pass"))

# A tibble: 2,490 x 9
   Normal PD    MP    TH    Py    KA    VT    SA    Test 
   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 Pass   Pass  Pass  Fail  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Fail 
 2 Pass   Pass  Fail  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Fail 
 3 Fail   Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Fail  Fail 
 4 Pass   Fail  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Fail 
 5 Fail   Pass  Fail  Pass  Pass  Pass  Fail  Pass  Fail 
 6 Pass   Pass  Fail  Fail  Pass  Pass  Fail  Pass  Fail 
 7 Pass   Pass  Fail  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Fail 
 8 Fail   Pass  Fail  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Fail 
 9 Pass   Fail  Fail  Pass  Pass  Pass  Fail  Pass  Fail 
10 Pass   Pass  Pass  Fail  Pass  Pass  Fail  Pass  Fail 
# ... with 2,480 more rows
```

I had to find some passes:

```
%>%
  filter(Test=="Pass")
# A tibble: 257 x 9
   Normal PD    MP    TH    Py    KA    VT    SA    Test 
   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 Pass   Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass 
 2 Pass   Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass 
 3 Pass   Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass 
 4 Pass   Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass 
 5 Pass   Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass
```

And there are some `<NA>` as well. This one stood out (#541):

```
  %>% slice(541)
# A tibble: 1 x 9
  Normal PD    MP    TH    Py    KA    VT    SA    Test 
  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Pass   Pass  Fail  Fail  NA    Pass  Fail  Pass  Fail
```

And the final tabulation gives:

```
%>% count(Test)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Test [3]
  Test      n
  <chr> <int>
1 Fail   2144
2 Pass    256
3 NA       90
```

---

**Data**:

```
dput(head(data, 100))

data <- structure(list(Normal = c("Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", NA, "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass"), PD = c("Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", NA, "Pass", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Fail"), MP = c("Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Fail", NA, "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail"), TH = c("Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", NA, "Pass", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass"), Py = c("Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", NA, "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass"), KA = c("Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", NA, "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass"), VT = c("Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", 
"Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", 
"Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Fail", NA, "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail", "Fail"), SA = c("Pass", 
"Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", NA, "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi Edward, Thank you so much for your help. Could you explain the methodology behind the code?

Comment: Using `case_when`, which is similar to `ifelse`, we create the `Test` variable based on your stated conditions.

Comment: Thanks Edward, I now understand the idea behind it. Cheers!